# Limit element in ForEach in Swift Ui

Tags: swift, xcode, foreach, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I can't limit my forEach for only 3 items inside my list.

I tried to group them or to just limit the list with only 3 items but I don't have the result I want. I have all entries of Firestore document.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Ballcap

struct MainPage : View {

    @ObjectBinding var dataSource: ItemDatabase = ItemDatabase()

    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.dataSource.items.identified(by: \.id)) { item in
                                    ShortArticleItem(item: item.data!)
                                        .padding()
                                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(self.item.categorie ?? "")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.black)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)

                            ForEach( self.dataSource.items.identified(by: \.id)) { item in
                                            MediumArticleItem(item: item.data!)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("The News Place"))
        }
    }
```

I would like to have just the 3 last elements in my ForEach

Comment: try to use suffix func for list, list.suffix(3) smth like that

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Array you can always use the array function `prefix(number)` to determine how many items you want to render

```
ForEach(arrayItem.prefix(5), id: \.id){ item in 
  //DO Something Here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try introducing a range:

```
@State var range: Range<Int> = 0..<3

ForEach(range, id: \.self) { 
    ShortArticleItem(item: self.dataSource.items[$0].data!)
                                    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ForEach(self.dataSource.items.prefix(n), id: \.self) { item in
    ShortArticleItem(item: item.data!).padding()
}
```

This is the easiest way that I found.
You simply add `.prefix(n)` after your collection and it will take only the first n elements.